# C# class inheritance hell

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm not able to understand why I can't set a Class3 object from a Class2 object type, if Class3 inherits from Class2 (see the error comments).

The same is working if I pass object type Class3 as parameter of Class2 (see Class2.Method())

```
namespace Classes
{
    class Class1 
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {
            Class3 item = new Class3();
            Class2.Method(item); // This works!

            Class3 item2 = Class2.Method2(); // Compile error!
            Class3 item3 = (Class3) Class2.Method2(); // Runtime error!
        }
    }

    class Class2 
    {
        public static void Method(Class2 item) 
        {
        }

        public static Class2 Method2() 
        {
            Class2 item = new Class2();
            return item;
        }
    }

    class Class3: Class2 {}
}
```

Comment: `Class3` *is* `Class2`. `Class2` *is not* `Class3`.

Comment: Replace Class3 with "Dog" and Class2 with "Animal" then see if you can answer your own question.

Comment: @GSerg - `Class3` is **a** `Class2`. `Class2` is not **a** `Class3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With inheritance, you can only typecast reference a parent, but never an inverse.  In your example, 3 is derived from 2 so 2 has no idea of any beyond it.

Now, to properly type-cast reference, wrap the object to get access to the parent's method.

```
var tmp3 = new Class3();
((Class2)tmp3).Method2();
```

The above is basiscally saying.  I know I am a class 3, but I want to LOOK like my parent via  (Class2)tmp3.  But when I want to call a method on that Class2 instance, I need to close the reference of that whole thing before calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

`Class3` is a specific kind of `Class2`. You can't assign any `Class2` instance to a `Class3` reference, just `Class3` (or inheriting types) references.

You can think of it in these terms: "Every Class3 is a Class2, but not every Class2 is a Class3".